# CodeIgniter Dropdown from query

Tags: codeigniter, html-select

I am new in codeIgniter and I having a bit of trouble with my database and dropdown menu.

Here is my function to get the information I need...

```
protected $tbl_name = 'club';

public function get($id = 0, $object = TRUE)
    {
        // select * from users where id = 0
        // check if id is provided
        if($id) {
            // id provided - retrieve a specific user
            $query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl_name, array('id' => $id));
            // check if object type is requested
            if($object) {
                // object is requested
                $data = $query->row();
            }
            else {
                // array is requested
                $data = $query->row_array();
            }
        }
        else {
            // id not provided - retrieve all users
            $query = $this->db->get($this->tbl_name);
            // check if object type is requested
            if($object) {
                // object is requested
                $data = $query->result();
            }
            else {
                // array is requested
                $data = $query->result_array();
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Here is where I call it in my controller

```
$data['clubname'] = $this->club_model->get();
```

and this is in my view for the dropdown

```
<tr><td><?php echo form_label('Club Name: ', 'clubname'); ?></td><td><?php echo form_dropdown('clubname', $clubname['name']); ?></td><td><?php echo form_error('clubname'); ?></td></tr>
```

but I get these errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: name

Filename: individual/individual_club.php

Line Number: 7
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 331
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your `form_dropdown('clubname', $clubname['name'])` call.  The second parameter is wrong.  `form_dropdown` expects an array.  [See the documentaiton](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

From your query's results, you would need to build an array of clubs. Something along the lines of :

```
// array is requested
$data = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   $data[$row['club_id']] = $row['club_name'];
}
```

Replace `club_id` and `club_name` with your table's column names for the name and id of the clubs.  After that, change your `form_dropdown` to `form_dropdown('clubname', $clubname)`.

Like this, `$clubname` is an array of clubs.

Hope this helps!